# What does »'ne« mean?

Tags: meaning

I read:

> Ich warte schon **'ne** Ewigkeit.

I suspect it means *I have been waiting for **whole** eternity*, or something like this. But I do not understand what **'ne** means.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

" **'ne**" is the abbreviation for "**eine**". The apostrophe omits the syllable "ei-". Note that this is a more colloquial writing and should not be used in a formal context.

**EDIT:**
As asked in the comments by the OP and answered by Eller, JohnDizzle, guidot and AnoE:

This construction does not work for definite articles.

However, it works with other indefinite articles:

- 'n = ein
- 'nen = einen
- 'ner = einer
- 'nem = einem

But it does not work for "eines" as " 'nes" is not used.

Comment: Thank you. One can guess. But will it work with others definite and indefinite articles in the following way: ein='n, der='r, etc.?

Comment: @Wolfgang it definitly works for ein = 'n eg. "Das ist ´n schönes Auto."

Comment: @Wolfgang It does not work with definite articles.

Comment: @JohnDizzle: It works with*nen* for *einen*, *'n* for *ein* and *'ner* for  *einer* the same way, but I never heard *'nes* or other forms.

Comment: @guidot, works for *'nem* as well; not for *'nes* probably because der Dativ ist dem Genetiv sein Feind. :-)

Comment: I would not say it does not work with definite articles at all. *das* can be *'s*, and *ins*, *aufs*, *im*, *vom* etc are even part of the literary language.

Answer (score 7):

In regions where the Bavarian dialects are spoken (Bavaria and Austria), you might more often hear in similar settings:

> Ich wart' schon **a** Ewigkeit.

Both, *»**a**«* and *»**’ne**«* are colloquial abbreviations for *»**eine**«*, but *»’ne«* is more common in middle and northern parts of Germany, while *»a«* has its home in the south.

(Note that there is also another minor change: The trailing *e* of *warte* is omitted in the south.)

Also the word *»**ein**«* can be shortened:

> Standard German: »Gib mir bitte **ein** Glas Wasser.« *(Please give me a glass of water.)*
> Colloquial, northern version: »Gib mir bitte **’n** Glas Wasser.«
> Colloquial, southern version: »Gib mir bitte **a** Glas Wasser.«

*»**einen**«:*

> Standard German: »Du hast da **einen** Fleck.« *(You have a stain there.)*
> Colloquial, northern version: »Du hast da **’nen** Fleck.«
> Colloquial, southern version: »Du hast da **an** Fleck.«

*»**einem**«:*

> Standard German: »Er hat ihn mit **einem** Seil angebunden.« *(He tied it with a rope.)*
> Colloquial, northern version: »Er hat ihn mit **’nem** Seil angebunden.«
> Colloquial, southern version: »Er hat ihn mit **an** Seil angebunden.«

(Note, that *»einem«* doesn't turn to *»a**m**«* in the south, but also to *»a**n**«*. Dative and accusative case often are the same in the southern colloquial speech.)

*»**einer**«:*

> Standard German: »Iss den Reis mit **einer** Gabel!« *(Eat the rice with a fork!)*
> Colloquial, northern version: »Iss den Reis mit **’ner** Gabel!«
> Colloquial, southern version: »Iss den Reis mit **ana** Gabel!«

---

This doesn't work with definite articles (*der, die, das, des, dem, den*), and it also doesn't work with the male and neuter genitive indefinite article *eines* (»Das Kind *eines* Lehrers« doesn't turn into »Das Kind *’nes* Lehrers« in the north, and in the south the genitive is even displaced with dative very often: »Das Kind *vom* Lehrer«)

Note that all those abbreviations are not part of standard German. They are part of colloquial speech or even of regional dialects. As long as you are not able to speak German without any foreign accent, nobody expects you to actively use such non-standard forms.

But when you talk with native speakers, you might hear such forms, and then you can remember what it means.

It's rather rare to find one of those colloquial non-standard forms in written texts. If so, you might more likely find the northern versions, because they are closer to the standard.

Comment: Wouldn’t “Er hat ihn mit einem Seil angebunden” more likely mean “He tied _him_ [up] with a rope” unless there’s an obvious masculine antecedent?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: In German pronouns refer to a grammatical gender, not to a biological gender like in English. When I wrote this example, I thought of *»ein Ast«* (*a branch*), which is grammatically masculine in German and therefore needs the pronoun *»ihn«*. But since a branch is not a person, it has to be *»it«* in English. »*Der Ast* drohte ganz abzubrechen. Er hat *ihn* sicherheitshalber mit einem Seil angebunden.« (*The branch* was on the verge to break off completely. He tied *it* with a rope for safety's sake.)

Comment: *eines* -> *von einem*, *des* -> *von dem*. Nicht nur im Süden.

Comment: *Einem* turns to *am* in south-western Bavaria.